# sequalizejs: Having dot in tableName adds double quotes to it

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

### What are you doing?

trying to fetch data from postgres table retail_lending.city_tax_reference using models, but when i use that in `tableName` its inserting double quotes to table name in the query

```
const CityTax = this.config.define('foo', {
citytaxreference_skey: Sequelize.INTEGER,
city: Sequelize.STRING,
property_tax_rate: Sequelize.NUMERIC,
minimum_property_tax: Sequelize.INTEGER,
}, {
tableName: 'retail_lending.city_tax_reference',
timestamps: false,
});

CityTax.findAll({
attributes: ['citytaxreference_skey', 'city']
}).then((project) => {
console.log(project);
});
```

`quoteIdentifiers` is set to false during establishing the connection

### What do you expect to happen?

_ Expected to model to run query `SELECT citytaxreference_skey, city FROM retail_lending.city_tax_reference AS foo` behind the scenes 
The above query works in postgres command line

### What is actually happening?

model is using `SELECT citytaxreference_skey, city FROM "retail_lending.city_tax_reference" AS foo`
the above query dosent work in postgres commandline as table name is enclosed with in quotes

Output: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "retail_lending.city_tax_reference" does not exist`

**Dialect:** postgres
**Dialect version:** not sure(hosted online)
**Database version:** not sure(hosted online)
**Sequelize version:** 4.39.0
**Tested with latest release:** Yes,  4.39.0

A solution would be great if there is any thanks

Comment: You have a table called `city_tax_reference` inside the PostgreSQL schema `retail_lending`?

Comment: actually i fixed it. You can look at the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property called schema which you add when defining a model like this

```
    const CityTax = this.config.define('foo', {
    citytaxreference_skey: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    city: Sequelize.STRING,
    property_tax_rate: Sequelize.NUMERIC,
    minimum_property_tax: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    }, {
    tableName: 'city_tax_reference',
    timestamps: false,
    schema:'retail_lending'
    });
```